# draw rectangle on canvas between 2 points

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm new to javascript and trying to learn how to draw on a canvas. The task is to draw a rectangle between 2 clicked points on a canvas.

```js
let rectangle = 0;

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  let x;
  let y;
  canvas.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (rectangle === 0) {
      x = e.clientX;
      y = e.clientY;
      ++rectangle;
    } else {
      xprim = e.clientX;
      yprim = e.clientY;

      context.beginPath();
      context.fillRect(x, y, xprim - x, yprim - y);
      context.stroke();
      rectangle = 0;
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.canvas_for_rectangle{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" class="canvas_for_rectangle">
```

Nothing is being shown on the canvas and I have no idea of what is not being done correctly as I am extremely new to the language. What am I doing wrong and what do I have to research?

Comment: Works for me. Are you clicking within the canvas area? (Also, note that event mouse coordinates are relative to the page view area while canvas coordinates are relative to the canvas area.)

Comment: I am clicking on the canvas, I also have some console.log(s) in the if-else and it prints that it enters them. I have no idea of what is being done wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to make the canvas bigger? It’s default size is only 300x150 if I remember right, so you might simply be drawing outside of that area. The size you give it with CSS isn’t relevant for drawing. I would remove your CSS for now and do:

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
```

Comment: that really did something. now rectangles appear on my canvas but really far away from the points I'm clicking.
I have other HTML elements before declaring the canvas in HTML, does that matter?

Comment: Cool! Yeah, `e.clientX`/`Y` are coordinates relative to the whole window. You want coordinates relative to the canvas, which is `e.offsetX`/`Y`

Comment: Yeah. So there were to problems that were leading to me seeing nothing: 1. canvas being too small; 2.coordinates being not related to the canvas. Thanks, your tips fixed my problem and my hate for Javascript is slowly decreasing!